# Redirect from webpage to whatsapp not working after first try

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

I have a link that opens a page which immediately redirects a user on the webpage to whatsapp with a message.
This redirect triggers a pop-up which shows 'pop-up blocked' on chrome. However, once the user selects 'always allow', as shown in the image below, the user is redirected and whatsapp opens the sharing screen with the option to select a contact or send to whatsapp status to share the message in the url with.

[image: screenshot of popup in chrome]

My problem is that after the user allows the popup (selects allow always) for the first time, the subsequent times it simply opens a new tab which shows a blank page with the url. Whatsapp does not open when there is no security pop up for the user to allow, since the user has already selected to always allow.

[image: screenshot of open tab when whatsapp open fails]

In js, I used `window.open(url)`.

I have also tried:

```js
window.location.href =url;
window.location.assign(url);
window.location.replace(url);
document.location.href = url;
```

Why does it work the first time when the user is prompted to give permission, but fails after the user has already given permission?

I have implemented something similar on a button when the user clicks and that works okay. I understand the browser (Chrome) warns the user when redirects are not triggered by user events like click.

However I would like to implement the redirect from a link functionality as a user shortcut, even if the user meets warnings every time. How do I get the WhatsApp opening functionality to work when the site is allowed to show popups by the user?

`day.js` code:

```js
let url = `whatsapp://send?text=MyMessage`
window.open(url);
```

HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta name="description" content="A countdown app">
   <title>Final Countdown </title>
   <link href="img/icons/favicon.png" rel="icon">

   <!-- ios support -->
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/img/icons/favicon.png">
   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar" content="#7b68ee">
   <meta name="theme-color" content="#7b68ee">
   <meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" content="grey">
   <meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" content="#7b68ee">

   <body>
        <div>
            Redirecting to whatsapp...
        </div>
        <script src="day.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

*Tested on chrome for android.*
I have used both secure and unsecure connections and all give the same result.

You can test here if open on mobile browser on a phone with whatsapp installed.
https://whatsapplink--rcountdown.netlify.app/dayofyear.html

Comment: This isn't a resolutive answer anyway I think the issue is related to the action not strictly initiated by the user. You can read on mdn that states literally: `Modern browsers have strict popup blocker policies. Popup windows must be opened in direct response to user input, and a separate user gesture event is required for each Window.open() call. This prevents sites from spamming users with lots of windows. However, this poses an issue for multi-window applications.`. Such statement doesn't touch the allow of the event but yet `Popup windows must be opened in direct response to user input`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open